# Shouldn't this cause an Overflow? It doesn't!

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

What's up with this, anyway?  I do a simple multiplication:

```
Int64 x = 11111111111;
Int64 y = 11111111111;
Int64 z = x * y;
```

And at the end of the multiplication, z shows a value of:

-5670418394979206991

This has clearly overflowed, but no exception is raised.  I'd like one to be raised, but...

Note that this is on Windows Phone 7, but I don't think this has any bearing on the issue.  Or does it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use a checked block as pointed out already by other answers:

```
checked
{
    long x = 11111111111;
    long y = 11111111111;
    long z = checked(x * y);
    // ...
}
```

Which results in an exception:

> OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

If you are just doing a single operation where you need checking you can use a [checked expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw%28VS.71%29.aspx) instead:

```
long x = 11111111111;
long y = 11111111111;
long z = checked(x * y);
```

You can also set the [/checked compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf%28VS.71%29.aspx) to have the default be checked.

> To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment:
>
> 1. Open the project's **Property Pages** dialog box. For details, see [Setting Visual C# Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288395(VS.71).aspx).
> 2. Click the **Configuration Properties** folder.
> 3. Click the **Build** property page.
> 4. Modify the **Check for Arithmetic Overflow/Underflow property**.

If you change the default to checked you can use unchecked blocks or expressions to get the unchecked behaviour again.

Comment: Note that the reason that unchecked is the default is because (1) 99% of the time integer arithmetic is nowhere near the boundaries, and (2) checked arithmetic is WAY slower. This is one of the rare cases where the design of C# chooses dangerous-by-default for performance reasons.

Comment: The x86 jitter uses a simple jno, branch prediction is always good, can't cost more than a single cycle.

Comment: Not that it was necessarily relevant to the design of C# but in this specific case we're talking about ARM. The behaviour of the x86 jitter is somewhat academic

Answer (score 26):

[Check it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw(VS.71).aspx):

```
checked
{
    Int64 x = 11111111111;
    Int64 y = 11111111111;
    Int64 z = x * y;
}
```

Comment: Bingo!  Learn something new every day, I does!  Thanks.  And thank goodness for SO.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
checked
{
    Int64 x = 11111111111;
    Int64 y = 11111111111;
    Int64 z = x * y;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Compiler assumes you want to do it that way and proceed with the Overflow. If overflow needs to be considered as exception for the operation, wrap the operation around `checked` and it will throw an exception at runtime.

```
checked
{
    Int64 x = 11111111111;
    Int64 y = 11111111111;
    Int64 z = x * y;
}
```

> System.OverflowException: An exception
>   of type System.OverflowException was
>   thrown.